# Split Java String

Tags: java, string, split

Title seems to be simple. But I don't get a good Idea. This is the situation

I have String like this in my Java program

```
String scz="3282E81WHT-22/24";
```

I want to split the above string into 3 Strings, such that

first string value should be **3282e81**,

Next string should be **WHT**(ie, the String part of above string and `this part is Always of  3 Characters` ),

Next String value should be **22/24** (`Which will always occur after -`)

In short

```
String first= /* do some expression on scz And value should be "3282e81" */;
String second= /* do some expression on scz And value should be "WHT" */;
String third= /* do some expression on scz And value should be "22/24" */;
```

Input can also be like

```
scz="324P25BLK-12";
```

So **324P25** will be first String, **BLK** will be second (`of 3 Characters`). **12** will be third `( After - symbol )`

How to solve this?

Comment: Is the `WHT` part is fixed? I mean, do you want to split by `WHT` or will there be any other characters as well?

Comment: You need to take a step backwards. Why is the first element `3282E81` second element `WHT` and third element `22/24`?. Only when you know the rules can you implement them.

Comment: No. It will change. But that part will be String. 
It can also be like this
`scz=324P25BLK-12`
So **324P25** will be first String, **BLK** will be second. **12** will be third

Comment: @BevynQ I am getting input like that from an XML file. in one tag. I need to split it into 3 values like I said in question

Comment: @Shiju last 3 digit of 324P25BLK will always of length 3 ?

Comment: How do you know to count the WHT as the second string, and not the E that happens shortly before it?

Comment: @Shiju in the end its always the first 7 characters and then the next 3 and the rest right...... I mean to ask is the length always same for at least a part of it..?

Comment: @Shiju you can use the `String.subString(<int>,<int>)` method to do the splitting but you haven't provided enough detail to determine what the indexes will be.

Comment: @Shiju if ur sting size is fixed then below is my ans

Comment: @DavidWallace because it has only one charcter and is followed by Numbers. WHT is 3 letters

Comment: if WHT and BLK etc of your String is always of 3 digits then see my Answer !

Comment: @Tarsem yes in that(before hyphen) last 3 characters has to be taken as sString and first to til that should be taken as another String

Comment: @Shiju did you tried my answer it may be exactly what you want ? as i am reversing the string which is before - and then taking 3 characters and then taking rest string be calculating length string

Comment: As @BevynQ said, you have to work out exactly what the rules are.  Then tell us.  Otherwise, all the answers here are just guesses, and everyone is playing green-tick-lotto.

Comment: I have voted to close this question.  It is not a question about programming, until Shiju works out what the rules are.  Until then, it is a question about guessing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your String's Second part `(WHT)` etc will always be of 3 Characters then following code will surely help you

```
String scz = "3282E81WHT-22/24";

            String Third[] = scz.split("-");
            String rev = new StringBuilder(Third[0]).reverse().toString();
            String Second=rev.substring(0,3);
            String First=rev.substring(3,rev.length());

            // here Reverse your String Back to Original
            First=new StringBuilder(First).reverse().toString();
            Second=new StringBuilder(Second).reverse().toString();

            System.out.println(First + "  " + Second + "  " + Third[1]);
```

Comment: I'm getting output like this
`18E2823  THW  22/24` the first two are reversed

Answer (score 4):

You can use a regex like this `(\d+[A-Z]\d+)([A-Z]+)-([/\d]+)` and using `Matcher.group(int)` method you can get your string splitted into three groups.

Code snippet

```
String str = "3282E81WHT-22/24";
//str = "324P25BLK-12";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d+[A-Z]\\d+)([A-Z]+)-([/\\d]+)");
Matcher match = pattern.matcher(str);
System.out.println(match.matches());
System.out.println(match.group(1));
System.out.println(match.group(2));
System.out.println(match.group(3));
```

Output

```
true
3282E81
WHT
22/24
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this to split the entire string in to two

```
String[] parts = issueField.split("-");
String first = parts[0];
String second= parts[1];
```

Use this to split the first string into two

```
if (first!=null && first.length()>=3){  
   String lastThree=first.substring(first.length()-3);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use subString() method to get this goals. 
subString has numbers of overloads.

for first string

```
String first=scz.subString(0,6);
String second=scz.subString(7,9);
```

Comment: But this is based on length. The String value length may change

Answer (score 1):

You can use following regex to take out the above type string:

```
\d+[A-Z]\d{2}|[A-Z]{3}|(?<=-)[\d/]+
```

In Java, you can use above regex in following way:

```
  Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d+[A-Z]\\d{2}|[A-Z]{3}|(?<=-)[\\d/]+");
  Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("3282E81WHT-22/24");
  while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group());
  }
```

Output:

```
3282E81
WHT
22/24
```

Answer (score 0):

if the length of string is  fixed  for scz, first,second and third the you can use

```
  String first=scz.subString(0,6);
  String second=scz.subString(7,9);
  String third=scz.subString(10,scz.length());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String scz="3282E81WHT-22/24";
String[] array = scz.split("-");
String str1 = (String) array[0].subSequence(0, 7);
String str2 = array[0].substring(7);
```

Then the split will be in this order :)

```
str1
str2
array[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could us a char array instead of a string so you can access specific characters withing the array.
Example

```
char scz[] = "3282E81WHT-22/24";
```

and access the separate characters just by specifying the place in which the array you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
       String scz="3282E81WHT-22/24";
       String[] arr=scz.split("-");
       System.out.println("first: "+arr[0].substring(0,7));
       System.out.println("second: "+arr[0].substring(7,10));
       System.out.println("third: "+arr[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out my solution -

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            String first = "";
            String second = "";
            String third = "";

            String scz="3282E81WHT-22/24";
            String[] portions = scz.split("-");
            if (portions.length > 1) {
                    third = portions[1];
            }

            String[] anotherPortions = portions[0].split("[a-zA-Z]+$");
            if (anotherPortions.length > 0) {
                    first = anotherPortions[0];
            }

            second = portions[0].substring(first.length());

            System.out.println(first);
            System.out.println(second);
            System.out.println(third);
    }
}
```

[Live Demo](http://ideone.com/6GGBR8).